# Change camera preview mode on changing screen orientation

Tags: android, android-camera, orientation

I am writing an application where I have to show a video and a camera preview mode in same screen. The requirement is when the screen orientation change to landscape the video and cameraPreview should show side by side and when orientation change to portrait then the video and cameraPreview should be bottom-up.

I am not sure how to achieve this. Can someone tell me is there any library available or if not how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

use the ionic native screen-orientation plugin and detect the orientation and change width and height according to that.